# Get table id by click in td using jQuery

Tags: jquery, identifier

I have a tr in a table header that contains several input fields.

Is there a way that by click on one of these input fields I can get the id of the parent table ?

**My tr looks like this:**

```
<table id="tableID">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" /></th>
            <th><input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" /></th>
            <th><input type="text" name="input3" id="input3" /></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        // ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you can use $(this).parents('table').attr('id');

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the click handler you can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

`$(this).closest('table').attr('id')`

Comment: @Arun P Johny Very fast particularly Jquery!!

Comment: Closest was exactly what I missed here. This is perfect - thanks a lot for the fast reply !

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#tableID").on("click","input[type='text']",function(){

$(this).closest('table').attr('id');

});
```

reference **[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

Answer (score 1):

You should delegate event to avoid multiple handlers, and then use `delegateTarget` to target current TABLE:

```
$('table').on('click', 'input', function (e) {
    alert(e.delegateTarget.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('#tdId').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('table').attr('id');
});
```

it works.