# How to get an ID of the clicked element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to **GET** `ID` or `class` of the clicked element. Can someone give me idea how to do this? I tried to get the `ID` of the clicked element but it's not working.

Here's my jquery.

```
$('.sems').click(function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Here's the full code where link is located.

```
if(isset($_POST['loadsem'])) {
    $stud = $_POST['stud'];
    $output = '';  
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT sch_year,semester FROM grades WHERE stud_no ='$stud'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $output .= '
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Semesters Attended</th>
                      </tr>';
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $sem = $row['semester'];
        $year = $row['sch_year'];
        $output .= '<tr>
                      <td><a href="#" class="sems" id="asd">'; <--- Here's the link
                    if($sem == "1"){
                      $output .= $row['semester']. "st Semester S.Y " .$row['sch_year'];
                    } else {
                      $output .= $row['semester']. "nd Semester S.Y " .$row['sch_year'];
                    }
                    $output .='</a></td>
                    </tr>';
      }
          $output .= '</table>
            </div>';
   echo $output;    
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct. Are you using document ready handler?

Comment: Looks like you need following code in one line `$output .='</a></td></tr>';` and `$output .= '</table></div>';`

Comment: @Satpal yes sir it's inside document ready handler.

Comment: @nethken, Please share generated HTML for further investigation

Comment: What is not working? Does the alert appear? Is the click event being called? Is it giving the wrong value?

Comment: [May this link may solve your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175970/jquery-get-table-id-by-click-in-td)

Comment: @epascarello alert is not appearing. And i tried to put it in `console.log` but nothing happened no value.

Comment: Is there any error in the console ??

Comment: The answer of @user2181397 solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Seem you need to delegate the event

```
 $('body').on('click','.sems',function(event) { 
    var _id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(_id);
    })
```

[Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, ***whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future***.](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Can you explain why my code is working and yours is working?

Comment: the both code perform same action , in your code action target direct to element but in this code it will search the element within the body tag if found then target the element and perform click.

Comment: @Soni and what's about this "_" in the variable name "_id" when i removed that the code's not working anymore? hmmm.

Comment: *"Seem you need to delegate the event"* - Why? Remember that beginners will read this answer.

Comment: I need further explanation because i'm just a beginner and don't understand complex code properly.

Comment: `_id` is just variable name. It is not same as `id`. You can name it anything you want

Comment: _id is a name of variable , instead of that you can directly use the element **OR** its property, No need to save in other variable. **(e.g: alert($(this).attr('id')))**

Comment: Okay guys~ Thankyou so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$('body').on('click','.sems',function(event) { 
   var id = $(this).prop('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Hope this will help you...

Diff betweeb prop and attr - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051491/difference-between-prop-and-attr-in-jquery-and-when-to-use-attr-and-prop)

you should follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) also.